# MySQL Can I merge these two queries together?

Tags: mysql

I want to get the results of these two queries together but can't figure out how to combine them. The goal is to get the total sales per month by product. I have instore purchases and online orders. Here is the first query to get the total sales per month from online orders:

```
SELECT YEAR( orderDate ) AS "SalesYear"
     , MONTH( orderDate ) AS "SalesMonth"
     , SUM( orderTotal ) AS "TotalSales"
     , products.productID 
FROM orders
INNER JOIN orderdetails ON orders.orderID = orderDetails.orderID
INNER JOIN products ON orderDetails.productID = products.productID
GROUP BY productID, YEAR( orderDate ) , MONTH( orderDate )
ORDER BY YEAR( orderDate ) , MONTH( orderDate )
```

Here is the query that retrieves total sales per month by product from in store purchases:

```
SELECT YEAR( orderDate ) AS "SalesYear"
    , MONTH( orderDate ) AS "SalesMonth"
    , SUM( orderTotal ) AS "TotalSales"
    , products.productID 
FROM in_storepurchase
INNER JOIN instorepurchasedetails 
   ON in_storepurchase.isPurchaseID = instorepurchasedetails.isPurchaseID
INNER JOIN products 
   ON instorepurchasedetails.productID = products.productID
 GROUP BY productID, YEAR( orderDate ) , MONTH( orderDate )
 ORDER BY YEAR( orderDate ) , MONTH( orderDate )
```

Any help on how I could get this into one query so I can get all the results on a single table would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you can use UNION:

```
SELECT 
    YEAR( t.orderDate ) AS "SalesYear", MONTH( t.orderDate ) AS "SalesMonth", SUM( t.orderTotal ) AS "TotalSales", productID
FROM
(
 select 1 
     UNION ALL
 select 2 
) as t
GROUP BY
    t.productID, YEAR( t.orderDate ) , MONTH( t.orderDate )
```

Comment: Seems to be dropping a row depending on which select statment comes first. Any ideas?